# dplyr not respecting group_by when applying cumsum

Tags: r, dplyr

As described in numerous questions on here, I should be able to take a data.frame, group it, sort by date, and then apply cumsum, to get the cumulative sum over time per grouping.

Instead, with `dplyr` 0.8.0, I'm getting cumulative sums that ignore the grouping.

Example code:

```
data.frame(
  cat = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), size = 1000, replace = T),
  date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 1000, replace=T)
) %>%
  mutate(
    x = 1
  ) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(x = cumsum(x)) %>%
  tail()
```

Now, I'd expect the last few rows to have `x` equal to around 300-something, for each group.

Instead I get:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cat [2]
  cat   date           x
  <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1 a     1999-12-31   995
2 a     1999-12-31   996
3 c     2000-01-01   997
4 a     2000-01-01   998
5 c     2000-01-01   999
6 a     2000-01-01  1000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your numbers. For me, all `x` values are roughly around 300.

Comment: For reference, I tried this using `dplyr` 0.7.2.

Comment: Can you tell me if you get the same results in `dplyr` `0.8.0`?  A part of me will feel better if its a reversion...

Comment: When you submit a [bug-report](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/new), I suggest you make the problem significantly smaller (perhaps 4 rows), either with static data or with `set.seed`. (I suggest you could demonstrate grouping problem without generating 1000 randoms, such as `data_frame(a=rep(1:2,2),b=1:4) %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(x=cumsum(b))`, expecting 1,2,4,6.)

Comment: Yup, its a reversion in 0.8.0...

Comment: yup, doing it now.

Comment: Actually, 0.8 isn't on cran yet, so I'm holding off... I wonder where i got it from.  Anyway thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't know where you got `0.8.0` from. The latest version on GitHub is `0.7.5.900`. Your code works fine for that version

Comment: Maybe you are referring to `tidyr` which is presently version `0.8.0` in my machine. But I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a classic problem when you load plyr after dplyr, nothing to do with your version of dplyr. For example:

```
tmp1<- data.frame(cat = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), size = 1000, replace = T),
date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 1000, replace=T)) %>%    mutate(x = 1)
```

see difference between

```
tmp1 %>% 
arrange(date) %>%
group_by(cat) %>%
plyr::mutate(x = cumsum(x)) %>%
tail()
```

and

```
tmp1 %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(x = cumsum(x)) %>%
  tail()
```

plyr's mutate doesn't understand grouping.

You can verify if this is the problem using `search()`